# How to add a Two Column Unique without ruining my Query?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, match, vlookup, google-query-language

This code works perfectly aside from one entry having the same name and therefore not making it into the outcome. It returns all 8 requested Columns in the order expected.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(Query(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(UNIQUE(T7IG!F:F),
  QUERY({T7IG!$A:$Q},"select Col6, Col1, Col3, Col4, Col7, Col10, Col11, Col15 
  WHERE Col10 = 1 Order By Col15 Desc",1),{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8},
  FALSE)),"SELECT Col2, Col3, Col4, Col1, Col5, Col6, Col7, Col8"))
```

I added to the  `UNIQUE` condition making it check 2 Columns so I get both entries with the same name. Unfortunately this makes it return only the 4th Column (The information in the inner `QUERY` identified as Col6, and in the outter `QUERY` as Col1), not the entire `Query`. Meaning the first 3 Columns and the last 4 do not appear when the Code is run. Only the 4th Column is generated and it's in the Column it should appear. All other Columns are blank.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(Query(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(UNIQUE(T7IG!F:G),
  QUERY({T7IG!$A:$Q},"select Col6, Col1, Col3, Col4, Col7, Col10, Col11, Col15 
  WHERE Col10 = 1 Order By Col15 Desc",1),{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8},
  FALSE)),"SELECT Col2, Col3, Col4, Col1, Col5, Col6, Col7, Col8"))
```

Any idea what I could do to make this work?

*I'm sorry if this question seems vague or perhaps is not clear, but that's because the issue that is caused by adding another column to the  `UNIQUE`  function makes no sense to me at all.

Comment: Share few sample data as text table or share a copy of your sample workbook. Only formula doesn't make sense what you are trying to do.

Comment: Please make your link sharable so we can edit it. What is the expected result you are trying to obtain? Please put it in the sheet, so we can compare any solution with your expected result.  I don't really understand what are your trying to achieve. Thanks

Comment: I need the first example from Sheet2 A3, but with the second example from Sheet2 A19. Example 2 has both the "IS-2" entries, Russian and Chinese.

Comment: I am trying to make a formula that extracts this information from a large set of data, makes a Unique entry for each individual Tank from A, based on Key 1 from J, Tank Name from F and Line from G, using Vlookup to grab the highest value from O, then return A, C, D, F, G, J and O.

Comment: Link should be for editing, now.

Comment: Your question can be greatly improved if you add input table and expected output table to the question. [Tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) are a better alternative than spreadsheets to show your data structure. If you share spreadsheets, make sure to also add images of your sheet to avoid closure of your question, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: I shared a copy but was warned to remove it. Creating a table to demonstrate what is going wrong would be an entire project of it's own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(UNIQUE(T7IG!F:F&T7IG!G:G),
 QUERY({T7IG!F:F&T7IG!G:G, T7IG!$A:$Q},
 "select Col1,Col7,Col2,Col4,Col5,Col8,Col11,Col12,Col16 
  where Col11 = 1 
  order by Col16 desc", 1), {2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}, 0)),
 "select Col2,Col3,Col4,Col1,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8", 1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. This is returning an error of sorts. It is claiming that the ",1" at the end of the inner `Query` is a 4th argument. "Query only takes 3 arguments, but this is argument number 4"

Comment: @ProfDingledong answer updated. see your sheet

Comment: Part of the issue I see with this is that it appears to `Concatenate` "A:A" and "B:B", but those are not the Cols that would need it. It would be "F:F" and "G:G" in the original data set. According to my understanding of this if it worked is, it would leave me with the Concatenated version of those Columns, which would not be the desired outcome.

Comment: @ProfDingledong did you check the updated answer?

Comment: Awesomeness! I see why this is working, though still don't necessarily under stand why it didn't work the other way. I guess with code, that's just how it is. Once I figure out how to mark this as The Correct Answer. I will do that. I am not sure how you gained access to my sheet after I deleted it from post. I greatly appreciate your help, but is there something I need to do to more fully remove that Sheet and my subsequent information?

Comment: @ProfDingledong once you post something its recorded in edits history: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73889485/revisions to remove that spreadsheet you will need to delete it from your Drive (even from the trash)

Comment: I can't tell you how much I appreciate this, but for the life of me, the code you wrote is a total mystery to me. The Col numbers in the first Query call don't line up to the Col numbers that are produced. This was only Step 4 in building the code that I ultimately want for this data. I just got hung up on this step and was unable to proceed without help. Now, I'm completely lost. Why are the Col Numbers out of sync?

Comment: @ProfDingledong in inner QUERY the Col references are offset by +1 due to added column F&G in front of A:Q in array {} construct. then the VLOOKUP return columns are also offset by +1 because we do not need to return F&G column from the query. think of the joint F&G column as a virtual column that guides the correct calculation and then its thrown out right before outputting the desired result

Comment: Once again, a thousand thanks. I understand, now.